# UIKit: indefinite rotating animation with random values and durations?

Tags: swift, animation, rotation, uikit

I would like to indefinitely and randomly animate a `UIView` rotating. For each animation, the values should be between 0 and .pi * 2 (a full turn), always in the same direction, and the duration between 0,2s and 1s.

I tried this, but without success, the view doesn't restart from its previous animation ending state but somewhere else.

```
private func randomRotatingAnimation() {
    ballImageView.layer.removeAnimation(forKey: LoadingViewController.rotationAnimationKey)
    let randomDuration = Double.random(in: 0..<0.8) + 0.2
    let currentAngle = ballImageView.layer.presentation()?.value(forKeyPath: "transform.rotation") as? Float ?? 0.0
    let randomAngle = Float.random(in: 0..<2 * .pi)
    let rotationAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
    rotationAnimation.fromValue = currentAngle
    rotationAnimation.toValue = currentAngle + randomAngle
    rotationAnimation.duration = randomDuration
    rotationAnimation.repeatCount = Float.infinity
    rotationAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    rotationAnimation.fillMode = .forwards
    ballImageView.layer.add(
        rotationAnimation,
        forKey: LoadingViewController.rotationAnimationKey
    )
    delay(randomDuration) { [weak self] in
        guard let self else { return }
        self.randomRotatingAnimation()
    }
}
```

The delay function:

```
func delay(
    _ seconds: Double,
    completion: @escaping () -> ()
) {
    let popTime = DispatchTime.now() + Double(Int64(Double(NSEC_PER_SEC) * seconds)) / Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: popTime) {
        completion()
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help